# Sending a generated PDF file via email using React/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, graphql

I'm creating an application whose purpose is to fill out a long form, the details of which are saved to a remote database so they can be recalled/edited later. When the form is ready to send out, I need to convert it into a PDF and email it out. Preferably, I would like to do this without using the user's filesystem, but if that's not doable I can work with it.

I've been looking into solutions for converting to PDF such as [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), and for the email functionality it looks like the standard is to use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/). However, I'm not sure how to hook one into the other, especially if I'm going to be avoiding the filesystem.

This is a web app that will be primarily accessed with iPads and phones. My app is built in React, using Apollo/GraphQL for queries and an Express server, obviously all sitting on Node.

Are there any good solutions to this problem? This is a bit of a crunch time problem at this point, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been tearing my hair out on this.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here... You want to generate the PDF and email it from the server (possible triggered by a request from the app), right? If that's what you want, use pdfkit, save to a buffer, and attach that to an email with nodemailer.

Comment: You say _"Preferably, I would like to do this without using the **user's** filesystem"_ -- and later -- _"I'm not sure how to hook one into the other, especially if I'm going to be avoiding the filesystem"_ ... take note that using jsPDF (or pdfkit) and nodemailer is happening on _your_ server, so even if you write a file it's not on the _user's_ system, it's on yours.

Comment: @StephenP That's an excellent point, I completely forgot about saving it server-side, heh. Bit of a "duh" moment, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do all of the stuff you need, though it's not the same process, it's essentially the same.

First of all, you will be doing all of this in the backend. The user will submit the form, you will get the data there and work from here. Once you have the data, you will want to create a pdf file. To do so, I use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf It does what it says, works like a charm. In order to use it, you need to have some HTML. I get the HTML using `ejs`, more specifically, the `render` function. (you pass your data to the ejs file you want to render, get the html).

Once you have the html, convert it to pdf with that module (save it to some tmp folder, overwriting whatever was there or whatever you want to do), you can use the nodemailer to send the file (check the doc, sending attachments is just a matter of adding the data).

This is what I do. Surely there must be other ways to do the same.

Comment: I must just have been staring at this for way too long, because everything you just described seems super obvious when you lay it out like that. Though it's nice to get a recommendation on a PDF creation tool, there were a lot of options I came across.

I haven't been using ejs in my app, just JSX, although that shouldn't change my process. Thanks for laying it out, I'll give it the old college try and report back with my results. :)

Comment: No, the ejs should change anything. Because this is in the back end, and the ejs file will have nothing to do with React. It will be used just for the pdf